# What is the default value of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX for llvm source?

Tags: cmake, llvm

I don't see how to figure out the default value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` for `llvm`. Can somebody show me how to figure it out? Thanks.

http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html

Answer (score 2):

LLVM doesn't set the default for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. It is set by CMake itself and depends on OS you are building on. For Unix-like `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local` and for Windows `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:\Program Files\LLVM`.

To find out a value for a variable, you can always just run `cmake` on the project and inspect `CMakeCache.txt` file generated by configuration step. Another way is to launch `cmake-gui` and look it up there.

Comment: Adding to that, [llvm-config --obj-root](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-config.html) may be the real subject of the question.